# A function without critical points is open?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function $C^{1}$, with $U$ open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.  If $f$ does not have a critical points, then $f$ is a open function.

I have been told that this is a classic result, but I can not find a clear reference to solve it.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Another argument: if $f$ does not have any critical points, $f$ is a submersion (since the codomain is $\Bbb R$). Any submersion is locally a projection, which is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a consequence of the  inverse function theorem. You may suppose without restricting the generality that ${{\partial f}\over{\partial x_1}}(x_0)\neq 0$ Consider $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $g(x_1,...,x_n)=(f(x_1,...,x_n)),x_2,...,x_n)$ you can apply the local inverse theorem to $g$ at $x_0$, so $g$ is open this implies that $p_1\circ g=f$ is open, where $p_1:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $p_1(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: Ok, It is already clear to me. Thank you very much